# Exploratory testing against ChromeBook

Tags: exploratory, hardware

We are doing exploratory testing against a web-browser based application on  ChromeBook.

I have never worked with a ChromeBook laptop before, is there any specifics we need to pay attention on when testing a ChromeBook?

What I can think of are:

- ChromeBook tend to have a low RAM comparing to other laptops.
- ChromeBook runs on Chrome OS, which may present a compatibility issue to some applications.
- ChromeBook is low on hard drive, which may limit on how much you can download from the internet.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some of the issues which may you will face with Chromebook.

1. Chrome Os is Frequently crashing for No discernible reason
2. Chrome cannot properly load a web page, it will give you an odd “aw snap!” error that means the web page tried to load but crashed instead.
3. Sometimes unnoticed issues like plugged-in headphones that may need to be removed before you can hear sound normally.
4. Chrome OS will occasionally run into a problem where it will keep reloading browser tabs – over and over and over, slowing down everything else.

For more details please have a look [Chromebook](https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/chrome-os-problems-fixes/2/)

Comment: Have you got sources for any of these issues? All of them seem like speculation, or problems that aren't specific to a Chromebook. For example, "plugged-in headphones that may need to be removed before you can hear sound" - does that not apply to all laptops?

Comment: @theonlydanever Could you please check out the link which I have added above